# Is normalizing/standardizing features and target separately a good method?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, normalization, feature-scaling

Suppose I scaled the features and target by creating separate objects, like this

```py
X_scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
Y_scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

X_sca = X_scaler.fit_transform(X)
Y_sca = Y_scaler.fit_transform(Y)
```

I am working with sequence prediction with three inputs and two outputs. Is there any problem with this approach? If yes, please give the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions

> Is there any problem with this approach?

**None** at all.

> Is normalizing/standardizing features and target separately a good method?

Depends on what you want to do. If you want to use the scaler in a pipeline or something like that, where you need two scalers, its a good practice.

If you don't have any special reason for wanting to scale them separately, it's more efficient to scale them with the same scaler. 
In most applications you don't need to scale the target at all.